# linux initcwnd and initrwnd via /etc/sysctl.conf

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcp-slow-start

Folks,
  As we know, the 3.x kernels have higher TCP default connection values, such as initcwnd and initrwnd.  For 2.x friends, is there a way to set these in /etc/sysctl.conf instead of the ip route way?

Instead of the following:

```
sudo ip route change default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static initcwnd 10
```

Is there a way to set the same in /etc/sysctl.conf?

Thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/558800/get-the-current-default-value-of-tcp-initcwnd-on-linux

Comment: perfect, however, any way to set this setting in /etc/sysctl.conf ?

Comment: Nope. The default value is a constant in #define. However, you may be able to persuade your init scripts to install the default route with the parameters you want. For example, on Gentoo, this can be easily achieved.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite answering the question but in December 2017 support for changing these values was [added to systemd-networkd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/323d9329e7a3d62a76d2f60b6884e1aa69bfe685) so you can now put this in `/etc/systemd/network/*.network` to make it persistent:

```
[Route]
Gateway=_dhcp4
InitialCongestionWindow=10          # initcwnd
InitialAdvertisedReceiveWindow=10   # initrwnd
```

The `Gateway=_dhcp4` line is needed if you want the `[Route]` section to apply to the gateway supplied via DHCP.  Otherwise add the `Initial*` lines to your existing `[Route]` section where you manually specify your gateway address.

Answer (score 2):

By "via sysctl.conf" do you actually mean you want the settings to apply every boot?

If so, you can write `/sbin/ifup-local` to run any commands as the last part of the interface start. The `ifup` script calls this with the interface name as a parameter.

So your `/sbin/ifup-local` could contain:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" == "eth0" ]]
then
  ip route change default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto static initcwnd 10
fi
```

At least this works on RHEL/CentOS. I have not tried Deb/Ubu/others.

Comment: What if its a different interface that you want to change the setting of, other than the default one?

Comment: There is no "default interface". The script is called with the device name as a parameter, so you just add/change the `if` condition to match what interface(s) you want to change settings for.

Answer (score 2):

In case of CentOS 7 the script called in ifup is /sbin/ifup-pre-local .
So i just made the script /sbin/ifup-pre-local :

```
#!/bin/bash

defrt=`ip route | grep "^default" | head -1`
ip route change $defrt initcwnd 10
```

And the initcwnd is set in all reboots and network restart.

Comment: on my CentOS 7.9 host, adding route change scripts to `ifup-pre-local` DID NOT work. The interface had to be up first, otherwise the route did not yet exist and therefore could not be changed. I had to use `/sbin/ifup-local`.

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL/CentOS/Oracle/Scientific Linux and other EL-based distro's:

Easy, just don't specify GATEWAY= in your /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file.
Then create a 2nd file called route-eth0 in the same place and write your gateway there:

```
  default via 192.168.0.1 initcwnd 10 initrwnd 10
```

This method:

- Keeps the network configuration in one place, where it should be to it is easy to find in the future and when servers are moved/upgrade.
- Avoids creating unusual /sbin/ scripts that *will* be forgotten 10 years in the future
- Doesn't depend on systemd